# How can I reshape this data?

Tags: r, reshape

I have some data to reshape in **R** but can not figure out how. 
Here is the scenario:
I have data like this

```
a<- c("exam1", "exam2", "exam3","exam4")
date1<- c(8.2,4.3,6.7,3.9)
date2<- c(11.2,9.3,6.5,4.1)
date3<- c(8.2,9.1,4.3,4.4)
dr.df.a <- cbind(a,date1,date2,date3)
    a       date1 date2  date3
[1,] "exam1" "8.2" "11.2" "8.2"
[2,] "exam2" "4.3" "9.3"  "9.1"
[3,] "exam3" "6.7" "6.5"  "4.3"
[4,] "exam4" "3.9" "4.1"  "4.4"
b<- c("exam1", "exam2", "exam3","exam4")
date1<- c(8.6,14.3,6.7,13.9)
date2<- c(11.2,8.3,16.5,14.1)
date3<- c(4.2,9.1,4.3,14.4)
dr.df.b <- cbind(b,date1,date2,date3)
   b       date1  date2  date3 
[1,] "exam1" "8.6"  "11.2" "4.2" 
[2,] "exam2" "14.3" "8.3"  "9.1" 
[3,] "exam3" "6.7"  "16.5" "4.3" 
[4,] "exam4" "13.9" "14.1" "14.4"

mylist<–list(dr.df.a,dr.df.b)
```

The example is for reproducibly proposes. I get the data in this format (dr.df.a and dr.df.b) There are multiple data frames in list object.
Now I need to reshape it a way to get one single line and variable names like 
`exam1_date1, exam1_date2 , exam1_date3, exam2_date1,exam2_date2 ...` and so on and essentially I would like to get data frame with rows of `exam1_date1, exam1_date2 , exam1_date3, exam2_date1,exam2_date2 ...` for every data frame in list object.
How I can reshape this data and which function should I use ?

Comment: What would output look like?

Comment: Output would be like data frame with single line and this `exam1_date1, exam1_date2 , exam1_date3, exam2_date1,exam2_date2 ... ` variables. Am I clear?

Comment: Which object represents the input?  What is `output` for?  It only has two rows and no numbers at all in it.

Comment: Might be output was not appropriate name! My list is the list of data frames that I must process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use reshape from base R:

```
new <- reshape(dr, varying = list(c("date1","date2","date3")), direction = "long")
new$newname <- apply(new, 1, function(x) paste(x[1],paste("date",x[2],sep=""),sep="_"))
new <- new[,c("date1","newname")]
names(new) <- c("info","exam")
```

Outputs:

```
> new
    info        exam
1.1  8.2 exam1_date1
2.1  4.3 exam2_date1
3.1  6.7 exam3_date1
4.1  3.9 exam4_date1
1.2 11.2 exam1_date2
2.2  9.3 exam2_date2
3.2  6.5 exam3_date2
4.2  4.1 exam4_date2
1.3  8.2 exam1_date3
2.3  9.1 exam2_date3
3.3  4.3 exam3_date3
4.3  4.4 exam4_date3
```

Comment: This is very good solution, but I need wide format, and I have now list object with multiple data frames.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
library(reshape2)

# convert the first row (the one defined by variable 'a' in post) into column names
dr.df.2 <- setNames(dr.df[-1,], dr.df[1, ])

m <- melt(dr.df.2)

d <- dcast(m, 1 ~ ...)[-1]
names(d) <- sub("_", "_exam", names(d)) # fix up names (optional)
```

Giving this:

```
> d
  date1_exam1 date1_exam2 date1_exam3 date1_exam4 date2_exam1 date2_exam2
1         8.2         4.3         6.7         3.9        11.2         9.3
  date2_exam3 date2_exam4 date3_exam1 date3_exam2 date3_exam3 date3_exam4
1         6.5         4.1         8.2         9.1         4.3         4.4
```

UPDATE: simplified `dcast` formula

Comment: I can not completely understand the formula in cast. Could you please be a bit specific? Thanks

Comment: All the variables are on the right hand side of the formula so we use `1` on the left and `...` on the right.

Comment: For this example your solution works fine. I am working on other files, and some how `cast` function without `id` argument goes mad and chooses wrong id. How I can tell the `cast` to choose right way to structure my data? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe what you mean is that `dr.df` has extra columns?  Try selecting out the desired columns first, e.g. `dr.df.2 <- setNames(dr.df[-1, 1:4], dr.df[1, 1:4])` .  If that is not it then provide a reproducible example.

Comment: I have changed example above to make it much close to my real data. How can I reshape this list object containing multiple data frames?

Answer (score 1):

If your `dr.df` object were a `data.frame` instead of a matrix, you can easily create a named vector as demonstrated below:

#### Create your data, but as a `data.frame` this time:

```
a <- c("exam1", "exam2", "exam3","exam4")
date1 <- c(8.2,4.3,6.7,3.9)
date2 <- c(11.2,9.3,6.5,4.1)
date3 <- c(8.2,9.1,4.3,4.4)
dr.df <- rbind(date1, date2, date3)
colnames(dr.df) <- a
dr.df <- as.data.frame(dr.df)
dr.df
#       exam1 exam2 exam3 exam4
# date1   8.2   4.3   6.7   3.9
# date2  11.2   9.3   6.5   4.1
# date3   8.2   9.1   4.3   4.4
```

#### The "reshaping" step

You can now simply use `stack` to get the data in a long form.

```
dr.dfL <- data.frame(stack(dr.df), date = rownames(dr.df))
```

The values for the vector you want are in the "values" column, and the names for those values can be obtained using `paste`.

```
setNames(dr.dfL$values, paste(dr.dfL$ind, dr.dfL$date, sep = "_"))
# exam1_date1 exam1_date2 exam1_date3 exam2_date1 exam2_date2 exam2_date3 
#         8.2        11.2         8.2         4.3         9.3         9.1 
# exam3_date1 exam3_date2 exam3_date3 exam4_date1 exam4_date2 exam4_date3 
#         6.7         6.5         4.3         3.9         4.1         4.4
```

Note that the result here is just a named vector, not a `data.frame`, as in the other answers.